# Change Bootstrap 3 column widths dynamically with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

How can I toggle the Bootstrap 3 grid system column widths (col-*) using AngularJS?  I am trying to use ng-class as shown below, but it is not working.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the grid structure in my view:

```
<div class="row">
  <div ng-class="{{columnWidth}}"></div>
  <div ng-class="{{columnWidth}}"></div>
  <div ng-class="{{columnWidth}}"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the variable in my controller:

```
$scope.columnWidth = "col-md-3"; //Toggle between "col-md-3" and "col-md-4"
```

The columns just stack as if I'm on a mobile device regardless of what I set the scope variable too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Should be like this,

```
  <div ng-class="columnWidth"></div>
```